# Who gained more successes in Iran-Iraq war?

Tags: armed-conflict, history, iran, iraq

From the infobox of the Wikipedia article for the [Iran-Iraq war](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War):

> Result:
>
> - Stalemate; both sides claim victory.
> - Iraqi failure to capture Iranian territories and bolster Arab separatism in Iran's Khuzestan Province.
> - Iranian failure to topple Saddam Hussein and destroy Iraqi military power as well as inspire sectarian divide in Iraq.
> - United Nations Security Council Resolution 598 cease-fire.

But which side really achieved more successes? Which side can be declared winner based on the successes achieved?

Comment: This appears to be more about history than politics. See, [Cutoff between Politics and History](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5836/26455).

Comment: These attempts at trying to classify a war as if it was an sports match are meaningless. What is more important, 10 small victories by one side or a big victory by the other? If one side loses more men but the other keeps the territory, who won? If one is more willing than the other to take losses, how do you take that into account? By all military metrics the USA "won" the Vietnam War, yet in the end it lost.

Comment: @SJuan76, *By all military metrics the USA "won" the Vietnam War, yet in the end it lost.* --- Vietnam was the biggest defeat of the USA in any proxy war ever. It can be proven by the fact that Vietnam is still a communist country.

Comment: Near the end, Iraq was very much suing for peace.  Can't remember exactly why Iran let it go, probably because they had bled themselves dry, but Iraq did not do well out of it.  Call it a pointless bloody stalemate.  But, yes, history question, this dates back 35 years and has limited bearings on modern day politics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither side can be declared an outright "winner" of the Iran-Iraq War. Both sides suffered heavy casualties and economic losses. The conflict is estimated to have cost over 1 million casualties and $1 trillion in damages. There were no major territorial changes as a result of the war.

While Iraq initially made some progress in invading Iran, the conflict eventually became a prolonged military deadlock. Neither side was able to achieve its strategic aims through military means, and the war ultimately ended in a ceasefire with the pre-war borders largely intact.

**The real "winners," if any, were the Western powers and Gulf states that supported Iraq.**

**The West's profit**

Firstly, the war helped Iran's Islamic revolution from spilling into other parts of the Middle East.

Secondly, the long and destructive war significantly weakened both Iran and Iraq militarily and economically, making them less of a threat to Western interests for years after the war ended. This created a broader power vacuum in the region that the West could exploit. The main downside for the West was Iraq's use of chemical weapons during the war, which the West turned a blind eye to in order to maintain Iraq's fragile balance against Iran's larger military.

Thirdly, the West sold large quantities of arms to both Iran and Iraq during the war, generating billions of dollars in revenue for Western arms companies. The United States in particular sold weapons to both sides throughout the conflict.

Fourthly, the West's support for Iraq during the war boosted its diplomatic influence in the Middle East. The United States in particular wielded more political clout through its backing of Baghdad.

Finally, the Soviet Union backed Iraq in the early stages of the war, but its influence declined as the conflict dragged on. The West saw the war as an opportunity to displace Soviet influence in both Iran and Iraq.

**The GCC's profit**

In addition to some common interests with the West, the oil-rich Gulf countries, especially Saudi Arabia and Kuwait, massively benefited from the Iran-Iraq war.

Firstly, with both Iran and Iraq's oil production disrupted by the war, the Gulf states were able to increase their own oil production and exports to make up for the shortfall. This resulted in higher oil revenues for them.

Secondly, Saudi Arabia and Kuwait were the biggest financial backers of Iraq during the war, providing hundreds of billions of dollars in loans, credit lines, and aid. This strengthened their political influence over Iraq. This actually resulted in the invasion of Kuwait afterward.

Comment: Your first point is unclear. You probably wanted to say that the war "prevented", rather than "helped", the iranian revolution from spilling to other parts of the Middle East. However, it's not clear how this would have happened. I don't see why Iraq's use of chemical weapons was a downside for the USA (the only "West" remotely involved in the war). I doubt very much that the amount of weapons sold to two ruined Middle East countries would be "billions". The Iran-Contra papers mention just $47M for Iran. Iran is considered the winner just like Ukraine will be the winner if it survives.

Comment: The way this answer is phrased sounds almost as if the West got the war started.  Thing is, Saddam was a Soviet-backed tyrant, who IIRC had a fondness for Hitler and fancied that his great military genius would let him pull off a Guderian on his enfeebled and divided neighbor that he'd been squabbling with.  The West may have helped him to avoid a spreading Iranian revolution, but that war was initiated by his stupidity only.  You could also say that the war cemented the Ayatollahs' hold on Iran, so hardly a win win for the West.

Comment: @Rekesoft, *I doubt very much that the amount of weapons sold to two ruined Middle East countries would be "billions".* --- You have to take into account that the West also sold arms to GCC by showing them Saddam as a boogeyman.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Saddam had an obsession with Iran just like Hitler had an obsession with the URSS. No need to push him to attack Iran, he did it on his own. That said, Saddam attacked knowing he had the USA backing. While the official position of the USA was one of neutrality (even selling weapons to both sides) facts on the ground included constant skirmishes with iranian vessels (initiated by the USA, not by Iran), one of them ending in the downing of a civilian airliner, or quickly brushing aside Iraq's attack on USS Stark.

Comment: @Rekesoft about doubting *billions* very much.  Much of the gear sold to Iraq was on credit.  Lots by Germany and France (much more than direct US *weapons* sales).  At least in the case of France, much was also underwritten by the state export insurance coverage.  It's not that difficult to do the financial setup to sell *now* based on *future* oil revenues.  In short, you are wrong.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_aid_to_combatants_in_the_Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War  Re. "knowing he had the USA's backing", citations please.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Saddam didn't had to travel to Washington and talk with Reagan to know that the US will see with good eyes his attack on Iran and wouldn't intervene except to help him. He could read that on the newspaper. A brutal murderous dictator, maybe, but not an idiot. And even your own link acknowledges that. It also says that Iraq received and/or purchased billions of weapons from Soviet countries, so it was hardly a major revenue for western companies. Total purchases from the West are probably under two billions, which is the minimum amount you can use the plural with.

Comment: @Rekesoft *hardly a major revenue for western companies* You plain don't know what you are talking about.  I am French and lived in France near the tail end of the Iraq War.  https://www.liberation.fr/planete/2010/09/21/la-france-la-guerre-iran-irak-et-les-affaires_680556/  : *From 1972 to 1988, 90 combat planes, 150 helicopters, 560 armored vehicles, 81 self-propelled guns and more than 15,000 missiles of all types were thus delivered to Saddam Hussein's army, **enabling French manufacturers to earn more twenty billion dollars**.*  You can be anti-US all you want, but please be factual.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Your data would be better supported if, a) you put your ad-hominen attacks where the Sun doesn't shine - I'm questioning this answer's conclusions that the West gained much with this war, not making an anti-US rant, b) Iran-Iraq war was from 1980 to 1988, while your data covers a twice longer interval, c) Given that, as you say, most of those sales were on credit, are you sure money was paid? Boasting about weapon sales is a common tactic to make the arms industry more acceptable by the public. I don't think there were any paiments after the Kuwait war.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: The last para of the answer is also patently ridiculous. The Gulf countries had nothing to show for for backing up Saddam in the end. Kuwait got invaded as "repayment" when it refused to write off the loans etc. Yeah, the GCC may have cashed in a bit more on their own oil sales, and may have stemmed the spreading of the Iranian influence a little, but on the balance of things, it's really hard to say the GCC came up ahead.

Comment: And exactly how much Iranian influence was reduced is also pretty hard to assess. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_Brothers which however pitted the Syrian-backed faction against Hezbollah. Syria and Iraq also competed, to the point where Assad (the elder) even took part in the first Gulf War.